# Silverlight Prism MEF: why use ServiceLocator to get View instance?

Tags: silverlight, prism, mef, service-locator

In Prism's IModule Initialize() method, the RegisterViewWithRegion() method is called to map views and regions.

What is the difference between those two lines of code? Why use a ServiceLocator?

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Region1", () => _serviceLocator.GetInstance<View1>());

_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Region1", typeof(View1));
```

Here is the whole ModuleInit.cs class for context:

```
namespace MyModule
{
[ModuleExport("MyModule.ModuleInit", typeof(MyModule.ModuleInit))]
public class ModuleInit : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    public IServiceLocator _serviceLocator;


    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ModuleInit(IRegionManager regionManager, IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
    }

    #region IModule Members

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Region1", () => _serviceLocator.GetInstance<View1>());
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

[Edit]

The [RegisterViewWithRegion Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5883994/1129654) MSDN site describes what the two different versions do:

```
RegisterViewWithRegion(IRegionManager, String, Func<Object>)
```

> Associate a view with a region, using a delegate to resolve a
>   concreate instance of the view. When the region get's displayed, this
>   delelgate will be called and the result will be added to the views
>   collection of the region.

```
RegisterViewWithRegion(IRegionManager, String, Type)
```

> Associate a view with a region, by registering a type. When the region
>   get's displayed this type will be resolved using the ServiceLocator
>   into a concrete instance. The instance will be added to the Views
>   collection of the region

So it seems to me that the only difference would be to use a ServiceLocator to resolve the type into an instance either immediately, or later when the region gets displayed?

[Edit2]

Found the answer [elsewhere on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5883994/1129654)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the main App is not supposed to know about modules.

When a module is loaded, it registers with the `ServiceLocator` and it has access to the `RegionManager`.
It can then, without the main app knowing anything about the newly loaded module, inject a view from the module into the main app (a new tab for example).

The `ServiceLocator` will ask MEF for dependencies, so you can always call `_serviceLocator.GetInstance<View1>()` parameterless, and MEF will go resolve whatever needs to be imported, no matter what you change in `View1`'s constructor signature.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. View1 is part of the Module, so why does it make a difference to the Main App when I use 'typeof(View1)' in place of the ServiceLocator?

Comment: @Nuitari I added a paragraph about it.

Comment: Ok, but when I call RegisterViewWithRegion with a Type as second parameter, isn't all I need the Type of View1? Why does the constructor make a difference here, I'm not calling a constructor?

Comment: Place a breakpoint in the constructor of view1, it should be called. MEF is like a complex factory.

Comment: See edit, it seems that both versions do the same but resolve the View instance at different times?